# Creating a test project for QML QtQuick

Tags: qt, cmake, qtquick2

I have a QLM project `MyProject` compiled with CMake, for which I wanted to add tests.

I figured I would create another project `MyProject_tests`, and a top level CMakeLists containing both :

```
MetaMyProject
|-CMakeLists.txt (1)
|-MyProject
|  |-CMakeLists.txt (2)
|-MyProject_test
|  |-CMakeLists.txt (3)
```

First CMakeLists contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(MetaMyProject CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_subdirectory(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(MyProject_Test)
```

Second CMakeLists is not changed, except I added `set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)` at the end.

Third CMakeLists contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(MyProject_ContraintsTest)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS QuickTest REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.cpp
)

set(HEADER_FILES
)

set(QML_TESTCASE_FILES
    testcases/tst_test.qml
)

add_definitions(-DQUICK_TEST_SOURCE_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testcases")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${QML_TESTCASE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::QuickTest)
```

Now for the component defined in MyProject to be available in MyProject_test, I wanted to add on the last line a `PIVATE MyProject`. It does not raise warning, but `import MyProject` does not work then.

What is the correct way to link my test project to the base project in order for all the components to be available in the test project?

Answer (score 0):

ENABLE_EXPORTS enables symbol exports from an executable, these symbols can be used in another library or executable. To be able to use a symbol in your qml, you would need to re-register the exported Qt Class in your MyProject_test/main.cpp using:

```cpp
qmlRegisterType<MyExportedClass>("MyExportedClass", 1, 0, "MyExportedClass");
```

Then you would be able to use it with `import MyExportedClass 1.0`

Comment: The main.cpp in its entirety is `#include <QtQuickTest> [newline] QUICK_TEST_MAIN(MyProject_Test)`, I can't register anything in it. Beside, my project does not contain any C++ class, only QML classes that I don't think I can register this way

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve with `set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)`?